# Real-time object tracking in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I have written an object classification program using BoW clustering and SVM classification algorithms. The program runs successfully. Now that I can classify the objects, I want to track them in real time by drawing a bounding rectangle/circle around them. I have researched and came with the following ideas.

1) Use homography by using the train set images from the train data directory. But the problem with this approach is, the train image should be exactly same as the test image. ***Since I'm not detecting specific objects, the test images are closely related to the train images but not essentially an exact match***. In homography we find a known object in a test scene. Please correct me if I am wrong about homography.

2) Use feature tracking. Im planning to extract the features computed by SIFT in the test images which are similar to the train images and then track them by drawing a bounding rectangle/circle. But the issue here is how do I know which features are from the object and which features are from the environment? Is there any member function in SVM class which can return the key points or region of interest used to classify the object?

Thank you

Comment: good tracking is done with probabilistic tracking mechanisms like particle filtering, kalman filter or TLD (implemented in opencv3)

Comment: @Micka Thank you for your comment. Im currently reading up on probabilistic tracking mechanisms. But I'm confused how to initially detect the ROI (region of interest) in image frame in order to track it successfully in the upcoming frames? All articles I read until now needs the user to threshold or use some isolation technique to describe the region of interest before tracking. Any help is appreciated :) cheers

Comment: your roi definition should come from your detection method, shouldn't it? E.g. you detect an object at some image position and now try to track that image position.